# multithreading httprequests

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am trying to create a class to send multiple http request simultaneously on different threads to try to speed up getting multiple documents over the internet.

I implemented this, but when I increase from 1 to 2 threads, execution time doubles, going from 1 to 4 threads, execution time quadruples. I would think it should be faster on more than 1 thread!

Here is the code, maybe I have some wierd issue.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace scomA3proj
{
    public class MultithreadedHttpRequests_James : IMultithreadedHttpRequests_James
    {
        List<string> Urls;
        string[] responses;
        public List<string> getHttpResponses(List<string> urls, int numThreads)
        {
            this.Urls = urls;
            responses = new string[urls.Count];
            List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
            for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
            {
                Thread bgw = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(bgw_DoWork));
                bgw.Start();
                threads.Add(bgw);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
            {
                threads[i].Join();
            }
            return responses.ToList();
        }

        void bgw_DoWork(object sender)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                int index = getNext();
                if (index == -1) break;
                string s = Urls[index];
                responses[index] = HttpRequestWrapper.getResponse(s);
            }
        }
        int counter = 0;
        int getNext()
        {
            int res = 0;
            lock (this)
            {
                res = counter;
                counter++;
            }
            if (res >= Urls.Count) 
                return -1;

            return res;
        }
    }
}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace scomA3proj
{
    public sealed class HttpRequestWrapper
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the HTTP response from a web page. Headers are used based on the useHeaders flag.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="url">URI formatted URL(example:"http://www.yahoo.com").</param>
        /// <returns>Returns Html source of requested page.</returns>
        public static string getResponse(string url)
        {
            string result = "";
            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                result = "error";
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Update:
I added this, but it did not help

```
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = numThreads;
```

I think maybe the network path I am connected to (university) is limiting to one outbound connection per pc or something and penalizing me for requesting multiple...idk...

Comment: Yeah...don't ask..was trying something forgot to remove it.

Comment: I don't know if this is related, but I was trying to do something similar using PowerShell jobs instead of creating threads directly in .NET. I experienced similar performance problems as you. I'll be interested in seeing what other ideas come as a result of this question.

Comment: Where do you capture the start and stop of the request time? Or, are you just capturing the overall execution time?

Comment: I can't find anything else. Time to do printf-debugging: Litter your code with calls to Debug.WriteLine and print actions and times.

Comment: I capture time before and after calling DateTime start = DateTime.Now; actual = target.getHttpResponses(documentUrls, numThreads);
            TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now.Subtract(start);
            Console.Write("done " + ts.TotalMilliseconds);

Comment: Could be the ServicePointManager's DefaultConnectionLimitj property. This was a gotcha for me some months ago when trying to speed up some photo uploading over http. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit.aspx

Comment: i ran your code AS IS - and it scales quite well. 1 thread executed 227 requests in 58 seconds, 15 threads - in 10 seconds. What page are you trying to get? May be it's your local site which slows things down? Try it on www.cnn.com - it's heavy enough

Comment: I was doing it on a remote site, maybe they put a limit on # requests and do some throttling.

Comment: a LOT of sites that deal with downloads have request limiters.  This may be a case of "it's not you, it's them"

Comment: might be my network path too. I am on university network, maybe routers throttling connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things could be going on here, the first is that you're reaching the connection count limit allowed for web requests. By default this is set to 2, so to change that, at the beginning of the function, you can update that to the number of threads you're using.

```
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 10; 
// 10 should match the number of threads you're executing
```

Other than that, it depends on where you're monitoring the execution time. If you're monitoring the overall execution time, you should watch out for the miscellaneous stuff you're doing, like implementing a Queue that you're not using.

Comment: I actually tried that in my unit test. It did not help at all. I am trying this on like 40 documents. I don't think the queue will impact execution time when it takes 7 seconds using 1 thread to complete =p...and I removed it since.

Comment: When you say that execution time doubles, what kind of degree of time are we talking about? If you just did one request, is the request fairly fast? Is it a matter of milliseconds or seconds?

Comment: single thread...~7s for 40 requests...2 thread ~14s for 40 requests..4 threads ~ 28s for 40 requests and so on...

Comment: James, you should try your app on a server instance you own; based on some of the earlier chatter you seem to be using it on some other site, which may be using any form of rate limiting against your requests.

Answer (score 0):

Using the new System.Net.Http.HttpClient, you can do this easily without rolling your own code:

```
public class ThreadedHttpGetter
{
    public IEnumerable<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> GetResponses(IEnumerable<string> uris)
    {
        foreach (string uri in uris)
        {
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                yield return httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Running 10 iterations against cnn.com (as suggested above) with the following code:

```
    [Test]
    public void YieldResponse()
    {
        IEnumerable<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> responses = new ThreadedHttpGetter().GetResponses(Enumerable.Repeat(uri, iterations));
        Console.WriteLine(responses.Count());
    }
```

Resulted in a console output of:

10
Test ran in 280ms

Obviously this will be dependent upon the capacity of your net connection and the site(s) serving responses.

Update:

I just stumbled upon this blog post by Stephen Toub.  This is really what you want and he even gives a concrete example in his comments specifically detailing what you're after!

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/04/10277325.aspx